# Are we ever told what duranium and tritanium are?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

*Star Trek* has been making up fictitious materials since season 1 -- dilithium, for instance, which (in an Animated Series episode, was said to have a helical structure similar to DNA).

Some of these, however, have similar names and are used in similar contexts to real world materials.  For instance, Duranium, which we're told comprises the internal partitions in the Enterprise D, seems linguistically similar to "duraluminum" -- which was an aluminum alloy used for aircraft frames and skins for many years, before the name fell out of favor, replaced by more specific alloy names -- and titanium, a metal both lighter than aluminum and stronger than steel.  We also hear about Tritanium, the main structural material of the Enterprise D, which also sounds like it might be a titanium alloy.

Obviously, there aren't a bunch of newly discovered elements in the 22nd, 23rd and 24th centuries, so these materials have to be compounds or alloys, or they'd be too radioactive to use in ships for long term human occupancy (all elements above atomic number 92 are radioactive to some level).

Are we ever actually told whether Duranium and Tritanium are actually titanium alloys or allotropes (alternate crystal habits) of titanium, or Something Else?

Comment: I have never watched Star Trek so this speculation might be entirely wrong : Tritanium = Tritium + Titanium  [Alloy]

Comment: @TheMadHatter ST writers are usually better than that -- tritium is radioactive with a fairly short half life, and is chemically hydrogen, which is generally Very Bad for metal properties (hydrogen embrittlement is a real world problem).  By the time you have your ship built, a significant percentage of the tritium would have turned into helium-3, which would just diffuse out of the metal and be lost.

Comment: @TheMadHatter Hydrated metals are brittle and not very useful.  And of course tritium is radioactive.

Comment: https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Duranium

Comment: *"Obviously, there aren't a bunch of newly discovered elements in the 22nd, 23rd and 24th centuries"* - Why not? Who says so?

Comment: https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tritanium

Comment: I've downvoted for lack of research effort.

Comment: Well, we have 118 elements and the ST:VOY episode *Emanations* starts with: "Captain's log, stardate 48623.5. There are two hundred forty six elements known to Federation science. We believe we have just discovered the two hundred forty seventh inside the ring system of a Class D planet."

Comment: Okay, I take back what I said about ST writers being better than that.  The reason we only know 118 elements at present is that their half-lives are measured in nanoseconds, and there are strong reasons nuclear physicists expect that the next four or five will be in that class or shorter before they start getting longer again -- and everything heavier pretty much *has to be* at least as radioactive as, say, thorium or natural uranium.

Comment: And thanks, @Valorum, I'll try to avoid asking any questions in future without a week's exhaustive literature search.  Which means none, ever, because I type questions while at work.

Comment: @ZeissIkon - I tend to downvote any questions that could be trivially answered by googling the question title

Comment: I don't use Google by reflex -- maybe I'm too old (I remember search engines like Yahoo and AskJeeves).

Comment: The science consultants would not have let them use actual element or even alloy names. After all, they are the ones who suggested fictional particles like baryons... There are so many, there's a Wikipedia page about the topic... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Star_Trek_materials

Comment: @KaseyChang Not sure if you were serious there, but baryons have been non-fictional since long before TOS aired.  Protons and neutrons are baryons.  Have been since it was realized their mass was so much more than that of leptons like electrons and positrons.

Comment: Sorry, cited wrong example.

Answer (score 3):

### Frame Challenge

A lot of the question is based off the erroneous assumption:

> Obviously, there aren't a bunch of newly discovered elements in the 22nd, 23rd and 24th centuries, so these materials have to be compounds or alloys, or they'd be too radioactive to use in ships for long term human occupancy (all elements above atomic number 92 are radioactive to some level).

Per [VOY1x09 "Emanations"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Emanations_(episode)), there are 246 known elements, with Voyager believing they've discovered a 247th.

> "Captain's log, stardate 48623.5. There are two-hundred-forty-six elements known to Federation science. We believe we have just discovered the two-hundred-forty-seventh inside the ring system of a class-D planet."

### Tritanium

Memory Alpha has plenty of on-screen references to the properties of [tritanium](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tritanium). It's apparently found as an ore known to be 21.4 times as hard as diamond. Per the [Star Fleet Medical Reference Manual](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Fleet_Medical_Reference_Manual), a reference book written from an in-universe perspective, the element tritanium uses the symbol Tn, has atomic weight 323, and atomic number 125.

It's used in starship bulkheads, armor plating, as part of an alloy for shuttle hulls, engineering tools, and even bullets for [projectile weapons](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/TR-116_rifle). It must be pretty common, or at least widespread, because Alpha Quadrant, Beta Quadrant, and [Delta Quadrant powers](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tactical_drone) make use of it.

### Duranium

The [Star Trek: Deep Space Nine Technical Manual](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Deep_Space_Nine_Technical_Manual), another reference book written from an in-universe perspective says duranium is naturally-occurring, and mined from worlds like Bajor (presumably alongside the uridium DS9 processed). The fact that it's mined suggests duranium is not an alloy, supported by the use of the term "duranium-235," which in normal chemistry nomenclature means "an isotope of the element duranium with an atomic weight of 235".

It's used in similar ways to tritanium: starship and shuttlecraft structural members. One notable stand-out use is in transporter calibration - in [TNG3x31: Hollow Pursuits](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Hollow_Pursuits_(episode)), O'Brien uses a "pure duranium" [test cylinder](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Test_cylinder) as part of an inspection/repair.

Comment: "It's apparently found as an known to be 21.4 times as hard as diamond." - I wonder which definition of hardness they are using.

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct, since in the same episode Janeway is surprised that they have discovered a stable transuranic element. *'JANEWAY: A stable transuranic element inside a natural environment. This is a first.'* If this is true, then tritanium cannot be used to make starships.